# Bootstrap3 nav mobile collapse doesn't work properly in chrome

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm just following a bootstrap tutorial, but I got stuck with some weird thing.

chrome and safari show mobile collapse differently with the same code.

I even tried 'copy and paste'!!

this is mobile nav-collapse on safari which it is a correct view.
[image: safari view]

but on chrome, it just doesn't work somehow.
this is the same one on chrome.

[image: chrome view]

i got no error on console.
I used bower to download jquery and bootstrap.

this is the html code. 
main.js and main.css are just empty files. 
this is just a very basic bootstrap... but I don't know why..
how can I fix it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Set the viewport so this responsive site displays correctly on mobile devices -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 3 Responsive Design Tutorial | RevillWeb.com</title>
    <!-- Include bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/main.css">
</head>
<body>
<!-- Site header and navigation -->
    <header class="top" role="header">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand pull-left">
                BS3 TUTORIAL
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span>
            </button>
            <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
                <ul class="navbar-nav nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
<!-- Include jQuery and bootstrap JS plugins -->
<script src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove `pull-left` form `navbar-brand` and see what happens. By default the brand link is positioned to the left. Otherwise you'll probably need to clear the float.

Comment: @Caelea nothing happend. The same look. I tried adding div.clearfix box right after button,it worked....only with the mobile width but not with the desktop width. the menus were below brand tag. the problem is why it works in safari as the way bootstrap is supposed to , but not in chrome.. is it my chrome? or everyoneelse?

Comment: I Did it myself! I just had to 'navbar-brand' and 'navbar-toggle' button in 'navbar-header' tag. It works nicely! thanks, anyway!  @Caelea